# Slow Scrolling in Recycler View

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I was designing a profile page for my app in android Studio with recycler view(Vertical), where each row has its own layout and I load it using the Recycler view adaptor...The 3rd and 4th row of my recycler view are again another recycler view(Horizontal) and they displaying images using another adaptor.  My problem is while I am scrolling my activity the 3rd and 4th row slow down the scrolling speed.  How can I fix it?

Comment: can you plz post code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not have to be with the adapters, there has to be with the amount of information that the recycler is going to process.
This link can help you.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2p99lw/recyclerview_scrollbar_with_lots_of_items_very/